# Echo retornando valor errado

Tags: php

Não estou entendendo uma coisa nesse caso:

```
$arr_4[] = "$arr_3[$i]<sup>$arr_22[$i]-$contador+$eletrons</sup>";
```

Vamos lá, a $arr_3[$i] armazena uma string de valor "3d", a `$arr_22[$i] = int (10)`, o `$contador = int(30)`, `$eletrons é int 26`. Se eu dou um echo na array criada nesse caso citado, é exibido: -1 apenas, nem 3d aparece.

Agora, se eu dou:

```
$arr_4[] = "$arr_3[$i]<sup>".$arr_22[$i]-$contador+$eletrons."</sup>";
```

Que eu penso ser o correto, não é exibido o resultado da operação... Ou seja, me retorna:

```
   3d^10-30+26.
```

Eu quero que apareça com a operação realizada, ou seja, que retorne: **3d^6**.

Comment: Tens de fazer a conta primeiro e por numa variável, depois concatenas com as strings.

Comment: Já tentou `$arr_3[$i]."<sup>".($arr_22[$i]-$contador+$eletrons)."</sup>"` ?

Comment: Ah sim. Cara, resolveu.. Qual a lógica do parêntesis?

Comment: Porque quando faço sem não retorna direito?

Comment: Não metendo os parentises ele não sabe que é uma função, pensa que "-" por exemplo faz parte da string.

Comment: tentei de diversas formas, mas não cheguei em 3d^10-30+26 a partir de `$arr_4[] = "$arr_3[$i]<sup>".$arr_22[$i]-$contador+$eletrons."</sup>";` foi essa a linha correta que gerou esse resultado?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Já ficou claro pelas outras respostas e comentários que você precisa isolar as operações matemáticas com parênteses. Como sugeriu o Sergio:

```
$arr_4[] = $arr_3[$i]."<sup>".($arr_22[$i]-$contador+$eletrons)."</sup>"
```

Para entender o motivo, fui verificar a [precedência dos operadores](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) `+`, `-` e `.`, e descobri que os três têm a mesma precedência. Como são operadores associativos, são agrupados da esquerda para a direita. Substituindo os valores do seu código, temos, sem aplicar parênteses:

```
$a = "3d";
$b = 10;
$c = 30;
$d = 26;
$x = "$a<sup>" . $b - $c + $d . "</sup>";  // "-1</sup>"
```

A saída é `"-1</sup>"` porque o código é interpretado assim:

```
$x = (("3d<sup>" . $b) - $c + $d) . "</sup>";

// portanto:
$x = ("3d<sup>10" - 30 + 26) . "</sup>";  

// 3d<sup>10 é convertido para 3 no momento da subtração:
$x = (3 - 30 + 26) . "</sup>";

// finalmente:
$x = -1 . "</sup>";
```

O manual do PHP explica a conversão de `"3d<sup>10"` para `3` numa seção intitulada [*String conversion to numbers*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion).

Comment: Muito boa, obrigado.

Comment: Cara, agora essa do 3d10 fazer operação é só php mesmo.  rsrs

Comment: @ZebraDoMal Incluí um link para a parte do manual que explica como isso aí funciona.

Comment: Sim, eu o vi...

Answer (score 7):

Eu faria assim:

```
$arr_4[] = $arr_3[$i]."<sup>".($arr_22[$i]-$contador+$eletrons)."</sup>"
```

A ideia de têr o parênteises é porque o php não faz concatenação correta de `.10 + 30.`. Precisa ter `.(10 + 30).`

Comment: É isso mesmo, só não entendi bem porque não funciona.. Que ele não faz isso ficou claro, né. rsrs

Comment: @ZebraDoMal isso tem a ver com a maneira como o PHP é construído e que regras de concatenação são permitidas. Dessa maneira aquele cálculo vai tratado como matemática e concatenado corretamente.

Comment: Os parênteses indicam aos PHP que deverá concatenar o resultado da operação dentro dos mesmos. Sem os parênteses e estando a usar `"` o PHP vai substituir a variável pelo seu valor.

Comment: @ZebraDoMal porque é o PHP, sabe como é... :)

Comment: @bigown só pq em php "2 bananas" + 5 resulta em 7 ? hahaha

Comment: huaha, isso é foda...

Answer (score 6):

As [*strings* em PHP](http://pt1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) podem ser encapsuladas com plica simples ou dupla.

Quando encapsuladas com plica dupla, o que acontece é que as variáveis presentes no conteúdo da string são substituidas pelo seu valor:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = 3;

echo "Resultado: $a+$b-$c."; // Resultado: 1+2-3.
?>
```

Para obter o resultado da operação indica, temos que dar a devida instrução ao PHP, fazendo uso dos parênteses para indicar que deverá ser concatenado o resultado do que se encontra entre os mesmos:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = 3;

echo "Resultado: ".($a+$b-$c)."."; // Resultado: 0.
?>
```

---

## O teu caso

Quando tentamos realizar operações no decorrer da concatenação de *strings*, temos que ter em conta que o `+` e o `-` tem precedência tal como o operador `.`, dando origem a resultados inesperados.

As [strings podem ser concatenadas](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) unicamente com o operador `.`.

[Operadores aritméticos](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) no decorrer da concatenação, tal como o `+` e o `-` vão indicar ao PHP que deverá ocorrer uma operação aritmética:

**Nota:** O PHP vai converter valores não vazios e valores não numéricos para `0` (zero) no decorrer de uma operação aritmética:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = 3;

echo "Resultado: ".$a+$b-$c."."; // -1.
?>
```

**A explicar:**

Descompondo o que está a acontecer no decorrer da operação aritmética:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = 3;

echo "Fase 01:<br>";
echo "Resultado: ".$a;
// Output: 'Resultado: 1'
// (concatenação normal)

echo "Fase 02:<br>";
echo "Resultado: ".$a+$b;
// Output: '2'
// ("Resultado: ".$a resulta em 0 dando 0+2 = 2)

echo "Fase 03:<br>";
echo "Resultado: ".$a+$b-$c;
// Output: '-1'
// (2-3 = -1)

echo "Fase 04:<br>";
echo "Resultado: ".$a+$b-$c.".";
// Output: '-1.'
// (-1 + "." = -1.)
?>
```

Pelo exemplo em cima, dá para ver a operação realizada pelo PHP até chegar ao valor de `-1.` no *output*. De qualquer forma, resultados inesperados é o que podemos esperar quando utilizamos operadores aritméticos em conjunto com operadores de concatenação de *strings*.

Comment: +1 pra quem não sabia que plica = aspas :)

Comment: E assim como `"Resultado: 1"` é interpretado como `0`, `"1Resultado: 1"` seria interpretado como `1` (que é o que ocorre no exemplo da pergunta, `"3<sup>10"` é interpretado como `3`).

Comment: Boa também. Parabéns.